# Link URI fails launch an app?

Tags: hyperlink, terminal, uri, instagram

Instagram sent me a link via sms to reset my password.  The link was "instagram://....". Obviously it is supposed to open up in the instagram app when I click on it, but it doesn't.  How do I launch this link to open something up inside the app?

Comment: What platform are you on? You say click, but I would suppose this only works for their mobile platform, since SMS is a Phone related service

Comment: Yes I am on android. I assume its supposed to open up the app when you click on it, but its not even a link. I've seen people post code on here for android like "gmail://..." etc which I assume is supposed to open up the app somehow.

Comment: /bump please help, this is a business promotion instagram.